# ActiveRecord error messages: translation for fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, internationalization

I've used the instructions specifies in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html
to translate fields of my model, but the labels doesn't come translated. What I'm doing wrong.

I have a `User` model with the field `name` and I'd like to have it translated to Brazilian Portugues (pt_br), so I got my pt_br.yml:

```
pt_br:
    errors: "Erro!"
    activerecord:
        models:
            user: "Usuário"
        attributes:
            name: "Nome"
            address: "Endereço"
        errors:
            template:
                body: "Por favor, corrija os campos assinalados"
                header: "Dados inválidos"
            messages:
                blank: "é obrigatório"
                taken: "já existe"
                too_short: "incompleto"
```

when I got to the page with a form:

```
<% form_for(@usuario) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

I sill have the field labeled as "name" and not as "Nome" as I'd like it to be.
I also have

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :pt_br
```

in my environment.rb

What is missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to namespace your attributes under `user`, i.e.:

```
pt_br:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        name: "Nome"
        address: "Endereço"
```

You can also install the [i18n_label plugin](http://github.com/iain/i18n_label/tree/master) to automatically translate the labels.

Comment: Excelent! It worked, but there's something wrong with your link (probably de underscore)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `<%= f.label :name, t('activerecord.attributes.name') %>`.

Comment: It works for the field, but I still get untranslated texts in the errors frame (when I leave blank a mandatory field, for example)

Answer (score 0):

What about [`human_attribute_name`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/human_attribute_name/class)? Is there since Rails 2.1.0.

I think it's better then any other solutions:

```
<%= f.label :name, User.human_attribute_name(:name) %>
```